# print <key,value> of List that have a specific value

Tags: java, list

I have defined a list as:

```
  List<Entry<String, Integer>> list
```

It has the count of the string. I want to iterate over the list and print all strings/keys that have a count of 1.

This is what I tried:

```
for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    if(list.get(i) == 1){
        System.out.println(list(i));
    }
}
```

I get "Incompatible operand types Map.Entry and int"

Comment: Why have you defined your list like that? How are you populating it?  What is your requirement?

Comment: I am populating a list by assigning it to a function that returns the sorted list.

Comment: `if(list.get(i).getValue().intValue() == 1)` ?

Comment: If you got that `Entry` from a `Map`, then you don't need to put it into a list - you can use `map.entrySet()` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it easier with a "foreach" kind of the `for` loop, like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : list) {
    if (entry.getValue() == 1) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
}
```

The idea is to skip the index altogether, and use Java's built-in iterating capabilities to shorten your code.

Comment: This seems correct but I get "Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a variable" and "entry cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: @user2441441 Here is a [small demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/VKFq0L). The demo also shows how to use `entrySet()` of the `Map<>` to populate your list; of course you can use the `entrySet()` directly, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use `List<Entry<String, Integer>>`...

You retrieved your `Entry<String, Integer>` from the list, but you're comparing it with `1`.  You need to go one step further and retrieve the `Integer` from the `Entry`, presumably with `getValue()`.

```
if(list.get(i).getValue() == 1){
```

Additionally, `list(i)` won't compile.  You may want to declare a new variable for holding the result of `list.get(i)` so you won't have to call `get` twice on the same entry.

Answer (score 1):

> "Incompatible operand types Map.Entry and int"

That's because you are comparing a `Map.Entry` reference with an `int`.

You need to get each element of the `List` as an `Entry` and use its `value` property in your `if` condition comparison

```
for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {   

    Entry<String, Integer> e = list.get(i);

    if(e.getValue() == 1){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I don't know why you have a `List<Entry>`, but there is probably a better way to iterate over `Entry` elements, ie. an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

You have list  of Map.Entry objects. You can iterate the list using below code.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:list) {
    if(entry.getValue() == 1){
        System.out.println("key":+entry.getKey());
        System.out.println("value":+entry.getValue());
    }
}
```